# Error while sorting in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sorting, datagrid, datagridview

I have to sort a DataGridView by descending, I've used :

```
DGV.Sort(Rang, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

but I have this result :

```
92
91
90
9
89
88
```

How I can to solve this to have : 92, 91, 90, 98, ...

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, so you want it to sort them incorrectly? Why should 98 come after 90? The result you're getting is correct as is.

Comment: sorry I meant 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, ...

Comment: And how's that different from what you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your column contains strings, in which case the order is correct.

Try a column of type Int32, and convert the values to integers when loading into the table.

Comment: I'm already converting values to int before I insert them into the column, but how I can change the type of this colum to int32 ?

Comment: @visamaster define it like **datatable1.Columns.Add("IntColumn", typeof(Int32));**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your column is set to String fromat when the contents are numbers.  If you can't just change the format of your column then you will need to provide your own custom sort procedure to implement *natural numeric sorting*.  You will find some assistance in doing this here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/csnsort.aspx